# Get attitude and longitude without using the map

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, dictionary, ios8

I want to get the current location latitude and longitude without using the map, is it possible to get like that, I am not getting that from searching the internet, can any one help me to find that.

I tried this with using the core location but even I am not got any thing.
please tell me how to find the latitude and longitude, thank you.

```
//remember to stop before you are done, either here or in view disappearance.

- (void) dealloc
{   [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in .h file:

```
CLLocationManager *locationMgr;
```

in .m file:on load

```
  locationMgr =[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationMgr.delegate = self;
if ([locationMgr respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [locationMgr requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
[locationMgr startUpdatingLocation];
```

add following delegates:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // Handle location updates
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location=newLocation.coordinate;
    float altitude = newLocation.altitude;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
// Handle error
    NSLog(@"error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

may you are not authorising the location from user. thats why you are not getting anything
thanks

Comment: how can i print the latitude and longitude from this

Comment: have you added correlation.framework in your project?

Comment: ya added but getting the error at authorisation,so how to get the autherization

Comment: if ([locationMgr respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [locationMgr requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}